# window.open function only runs once in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I have this text called 'Documentation', with a normal href when i left-click. But when i right click it opens a popup window, as it should. It works great when i only have one id, but lets say i choose 10 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], then 9 will be the only one linked to once: EditText?testjobid=9. The link also get attached to the 'Documentation' with id = 0. What am i doing wrong?

```php
foreach ($AllTestResultsTestJob as $TestJob)
  {
    $testjobid    = $TestJob['TestjobId'];
    echo "<th style=''><center><a id='EditText' style='color:#000' class='links' href= 'Documentation?testjobid=".$testjobid."' target='_blank'>Documentation</th>"; 

  </center>
    </th>";
```

```php
echo"
    <script>
    document.getElementById('EditText').onmousedown = function(event) {


      if (event.which == 3) {
        window.open('EditText?testjobid=".$testjobid."', 'myWindow', 'width=1000,height=390');
      }
    }
    </script>
    ";
```

Comment: Element ID's need to be unique. It appears as though for 10 jobs, you would echo out 10 different `a` elements, but all with the same `EditText` ID. You should use your `$testjobid` as part of the ID when creating these elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using the same **id='EditText'** for multiple element, so you should change your id and select those link with another selector.

So change your link to :

```
 echo "<th style=''><center><a id='EditText-".$testjobid."' style='color:#000' class='links' href= 'Documentation?testjobid=".$testjobid."' target='_blank'>Documentation</th>";
```

And change your event to :

```
echo"
    <script>
    document.getElementById('EditText-".$testjobid."').onmousedown = function(event) {


      if (event.which == 3) {
        window.open('EditText?testjobid=".$testjobid."', 'myWindow', 'width=1000,height=390');
      }
    }
    </script>
    ";
```

Comment: Well now id = 9 has the link: EditText?testjobid=9.
But the other 'Documentation' doesn't work when i right-click?

Comment: Have you put the script part in your foreach ? And left click should open "Documentation?testjobid=" and right click "EditText?testjobid="

Comment: Yes, the script is not inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Well, you should either add it in your loop so that the right click event is added for each element, or add the event dynamically to all <a> after you created them. So if you want it to work easily just now, add your script part after the creation of your link

Comment: I added the <script> inside the foreach loop and now it works! Thanks!